# Getting an error while trying to read virtually populate array of comments

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

```js
// model
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "title is required"],
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "description is required"],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } }
);

postSchema.virtual("comments", {
  ref: "Comment",
  foreignField: "post",
  localField: "_id",
});
const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
export default Post;

// post controller
export const getPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments");
    res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json(err);
  }
};

//react code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/posts/60d6463869eabd04241e18eb");
        setPost(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>hello</h3>
      {/* <h1>
        {post.comments.map((c) => (
          <h2>{c.user.name}</h2>
        ))}
      </h1> */}
      <p style={{ color: "gray" }}>{post.desc}</p>
      {post.comments.map((c) => (
        <p key={c._id}>
          <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold", textTransform: "uppercase" }}>
            {c.user.name}:{" "}
          </span>
          {c.comment}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Hello good day, please i have an issue with this code, i'm able to read other fields except the comments field which i virtually populated it, could this be a problem with virtual populate or something else .
this is the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: post.comments is undefined
App App.js:26
React 17
js index.js:5
js main.chunk.js:282
Webpack 7
The above error occurred in the  component:

App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:31:81

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.